# Ubuntu boot not loading

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-10

I encountered a problem with loading my ubuntu boot - I am using a double boot with Windows 10 and Ubuntu, after installation everything worked correctly for a few hours, then I restarted my computer and encountered what is probably a grub error with message "Minimal BASH like line editing is supported...", and I couldn't boot the installed Ubuntu (when I boot into Windows, everything is fine). I tried to put up a live session from a USB and done boot repair, but after completing it, nothing changed - I still get the same error when I try to boot Ubuntu. I noticed that there is not a possibility to reinstall grub when I use the boot repair app, so that might be the problem, but as a Linux newbie, I am not really sure. Is there anything I can do to resolve this?  Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am attaching a pastebin from my boot repair session - http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/V6yhZ5Ty6Y/ 
In advance, thanks for your help.

Comment: No Ubuntu system on your hard drive?

Comment: How would that be possible? I finished the installation and was able to use the system normally for a few hours. Or maybe I am not getting your point, sorry

Comment: OK. So which partition is the system installed on?

Comment: @PaulBenson I let the installer create the partitions during installation, and as I cannot seem them from Windows (or can I?), I don't really know how it created the partitions. Is there a way of finding out?

Comment: @heynnema The flash key is the one I started my installation from, but I don't think I installed my OS there. The installation even got completed and worked without the USB.

Comment: Then sda4 is suspect... as it appears to be an unknown file system there. If you can give us a screenshot of gparted, it might be helpful.

Comment: Ok, I will have to download the app, will post the screenshot when available

Comment: @xDeeZee -sda4 is Windows MRP - nothing to do with Ubuntu. In fact I cannot see any instalment of Ubuntu. If you scroll down to line 368 on your pastebin, where is Ubuntu shown on sda? I'd expect to see at least one partition to show an ext4 format. As you can see it's all NTFS, which is Windows

Comment: yeah, I understand, but like, the OS had to be installed - I used it, downloaded updates, everything worked fine for a few hours. I am not really skilled in the pastebin stuff, so I don't know about that. What do you think I should do? Should I just uninstall ubuntu and reinstall again?

Comment: I'm guessing that somehow your Ubuntu partition managed to get overwritten. The best way to tackle this is to boot to Windows, run `diskmgmt.msc` and see if any drives are shown as unidentified, ie not NTFS or FAT32, note the size and then tell us what this partition is.

Comment: There are 7 partitions present in the disc managment - 1 of those is PBR_DRV with 20GB of allocated space, out of which 11.27GB is free space. This is probably the only partition that could fit ubuntu, other two partitions that were created during the installation are around 1GB in size. The PBR_DRV has NT file system, though

Comment: There are actually 8 shown. For all I know that 20 GB could be your Windows system. The description in Pastebin says W. Recovery Environment. You actually have 3 different ones, the other 2 are much smaller. What I need to know is your C: drive. Is that the 25GB one? Can you also confirm where your data resides? Is that the 883GB one?

Comment: My C: drive is the bigger one - the 883GB. That it where my data is. The 25GB is the D drive